# Git Bash Logout from Current account

Tags: git, git-bash

I want to login to different git account using git bash. It is logged in by another account. How to switch accounts in gitbash?

I have removed generic credentials from control panel --> Windows credentials --> Generic credentials but it didn't help.

Also tried to add

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

Comment: how tit you clone the repo, via `HTTPS` or via `ssh`?

Comment: Bash never *logs in*, so it never has to *log out*. You need to track down the software that *does* do the logging in (it's not Git either!—Git does come with some "credential helpers", which do that sort of thing, but there are many to choose from and people download third-party ones, so there's no easy way to say which one you have). Note that `user.name` and `user.email` are not log-in credentials: they are used only when making *new commits*, which you do on your PC, without logging in anywhere (well, except your own PC).

Answer (score 0):

A friend was facing this issue and what he did was..
He went to Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Manage your credentials -> Windows Credentials.
Under generic credentials there were some credentials relevant to github. he removed them and he was good to go.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this. Its not working